# Loop through all object properties at runtime

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to create an Objective-C base class that performs an operation on all properties (of varying types) at runtime. Since the names and types of the properties will not always be known, how can I do something like this?

```
@implementation SomeBaseClass

- (NSString *)checkAllProperties
{
    for (property in properties) {
        // Perform a check on the property
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** This would be particularly useful in a custom `- (NSString *)description:` override.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To expand on mvds' answer (started writing this before I saw his), here's a little sample program that uses the Objective-C runtime API to loop through and print information about each property in a class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface TestClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *lastName;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger *age;

@end

@implementation TestClass

@synthesize firstName;
@synthesize lastName;
@synthesize age;

@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        unsigned int numberOfProperties = 0;
        objc_property_t *propertyArray = class_copyPropertyList([TestClass class], &numberOfProperties);

        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < numberOfProperties; i++)
        {
            objc_property_t property = propertyArray[i];
            NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:property_getName(property)];
            NSString *attributesString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:property_getAttributes(property)];
            NSLog(@"Property %@ attributes: %@", name, attributesString);
        }
        free(propertyArray);
    }
}
```

Output:

> Property age attributes: T^q,Vage
>   Property lastName attributes: T@"NSString",&,N,VlastName
>   Property firstName attributes: T@"NSString",&,N,VfirstName

Note that this program needs to be compiled with ARC turned on.

Comment: A good followup question would be how to return the values of each dynamically... I'm thinking dynamically create an accessor, but syntactically, I'm still trying to figure that out.

Comment: There are a couple ways you could do that, but the most straightforward would be to use KVC: `id value = [self valueForKey:@"propertyName"]`. Gets a little more complicated where you have both primitive (int, float, etc) and object (NSString, etc) return types, but the basic premise will work.

Comment: It's meant to be compiled with ARC turned on (should have mentioned that in my answer).

Comment: [self valueForKey:@"propertyName"] works for basic types, what about self defined types? how to get the properties for custom class? thanks!!

Comment: I may not understand exactly what you're asking. `[self valueForKey:@"propertyName"]` works just fine for properties with a type which is a custom class. `-valueForKey:`'s return type is id.

Answer (score 15):

Use

```
objc_property_t * class_copyPropertyList(Class cls, unsigned int *outCount)
```

and read https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html on how to do this exactly.

Some code to get you going:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

unsigned int count=0;
objc_property_t *props = class_copyPropertyList([self class],&count);
for ( int i=0;i<count;i++ )
{
    const char *name = property_getName(props[i]); 
    NSLog(@"property %d: %s",i,name);
}
```

Comment: Stellar. Perfect resource for closer-to-the-metal runtime madness.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works good, how do i copy one objects properties to other at runtime?

Comment: @PavanSaberjack using `valueForKey:` and `setValue:forKey:`, where you have to take notice that `char *name` cannot be used as object (i.e. as `NSString`) without some form of conversion.

Comment: @mvds I'm having this problem where `class_copyPropertyList` not returning the parent class property list when we use that code in a subclass, any idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Adding some detial to @mvds:

```
unsigned int count=0;
objc_property_t *props = class_copyPropertyList([self class],&count);
for ( int i=0;i<count;i++ )
{
    const char *name = property_getName(props[i]);
    NSString* dataToGet = [NSString swf:@"%s",name];
    @try { // in case of this pair not key value coding-compliant
        id value = [barButton valueForKey:dataToGet];
        NSLog(@"prop %d: %s  %@",i,name, value);
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        // NSLog(@"Exception:%@",exception);
    }
    @finally {
        // Display Alternative
    }
}
```

Please give @mvds the upvote.