# Debugging subtle iOS view layout issues

Tags: objective-c, ios, debugging, object, uiviewcontroller

Lately I've been running into some subtle layout issues in my iOS app. For example displaying a viewController from one part of the app causes the layout of some subviews to be altered (the z-axis ordering changes). Another subtle issue is the navigation bar flickering slightly.

**What are some techniques for debugging these issues?**

I'm especially interested in printing/logging properties of objects. For example I'd like to just dump/print/log all properties of the viewController referenced above to see exactly what changes. Then perhaps one can use symbolic breakpoints to pin-point the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use KVO to observe frames changing, so you know what changes when, from and to what values. You can even use it to fix properties to some contant value. (See [Prevent indentation of UITableViewCell (contentView) while editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789467/prevent-indentation-of-uitableviewcell-contentview-while-editing/8935622#8935622))

You can use reflection to loop through all properties of an object. I don't know how such a broad approach would help you, but it is possible. (See [Loop through all object properties at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269372/loop-through-all-object-properties-at-runtime/9269413#9269413))

Answer (score 2):

Check out [DCIntrospect](https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCIntrospect). It's a tool that can be very helpful for looking at view's info conveniently.

Answer (score 1):

Another technique to use is to subclass a UIView with override methods for re-positioning a view, or other aspects - then you can set breakpoints or log when the frame changes, or other attributes.

To use the UIView debugging class you can just change the type of a View in InterfaceBuilder to be your custom view type instead of UIView.

Answer (score 1):

Use iOS App layout Debugging tool
revealapp.com
Just integrate revealapp SDK in your app and work as firebug