# Is there a way to log all the property values of an Objective-C instance

Tags: objective-c, properties, nslog

I was just wondering if there is a quick and easy way of printing out to the log all of the various values of the properties to my class for debugging purposes. Like I would like to know what the values of all of the BOOLs, floats, etc. are.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269372/loop-through-all-object-properties-at-runtime) seems the have the answer to your question.

#### Update:

I got curious and made a catagory:

```
//Using Xcode 4.5.2 - iOS 6 - LLDB - Automatic Reference Counting

//NSObject+logProperties.h    
@interface NSObject (logProperties)
- (void) logProperties;
@end

//NSObject+logProperties.m
#import "NSObject+logProperties.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation NSObject (logProperties)

- (void) logProperties {

    NSLog(@"----------------------------------------------- Properties for object %@", self);

    @autoreleasepool {
        unsigned int numberOfProperties = 0;
        objc_property_t *propertyArray = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &numberOfProperties);
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < numberOfProperties; i++) {
            objc_property_t property = propertyArray[i];
            NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:property_getName(property)];
            NSLog(@"Property %@ Value: %@", name, [self valueForKey:name]);
        }
        free(propertyArray);
    }    
    NSLog(@"-----------------------------------------------");
}

@end
```

Include it in your class: `#import "NSObject+logProperties.h"`

and call `[self logProperties];` to those properties!

Comment: @Tieme I like _this kind of thing_.. but I like it to look pretty, and be SUPER short, hence.. [A concise category on NSObject to log all declared properties, pretty-like, using minimal SLOC.](https://gist.github.com/b51a60dac974b9f952a0)  (Also, yours made my programs crash )

Comment: @AlexGray I tried yours, which seems very interesting. However, it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 9):

There are now these methods on `NSObject` :

```
@interface NSObject (Private)
-(id)_ivarDescription;
-(id)_shortMethodDescription;
-(id)_methodDescription;
@end
```

In swift:

```
myObject.perform("_ivarDescription")
```

Thanks to [this article](https://bou.io/ExtendedTypeInfoInObjC.html)

Answer (score 8):

The current answers just show how to do it for properties. If you want every instance variable printed out you could do something like the below.

```
- (void)logAllProperties {
    unsigned int count;
    Ivar *ivars = class_copyIvarList([self class], &count);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        Ivar ivar = ivars[i];

        const char *name = ivar_getName(ivar);
        const char *type = ivar_getTypeEncoding(ivar);
        ptrdiff_t offset = ivar_getOffset(ivar);

        if (strncmp(type, "i", 1) == 0) {
            int intValue = *(int*)((uintptr_t)self + offset);
            NSLog(@"%s = %i", name, intValue);
        } else if (strncmp(type, "f", 1) == 0) {
            float floatValue = *(float*)((uintptr_t)self + offset);
            NSLog(@"%s = %f", name, floatValue);
        } else if (strncmp(type, "@", 1) == 0) {
            id value = object_getIvar(self, ivar);
            NSLog(@"%s = %@", name, value);
        }
        // And the rest for other type encodings
    }
    free(ivars);
}
```

Although I wouldn't particularly suggest doing this in practice, but if it's for debug purposes then that's fine. You could implement this as a category on `NSObject` and keep it lying around for use when debugging. If completed for all type encodings then it could make for a very nice little method.

Answer (score 0):

yes, one way would be to ask for all properties and then use KVC for example:

```
//properties
unsigned int cProperties = 0;
objc_property_t *props = class_copyPropertyList(self.class, &cProperties);
for(int i = 0; i < cProperties; i++) {
    const char *name = property_getName(props[i]);
    NSLog(@"%@=%@", name, [self valueForKey:name];
}
```

an alternate way is to go through all the methods of a class, get the return type, invoke and print it

Comment: Of course this only works for objects, not primitive types like floats and bool. How would you go about to solve the problem with the format specifier in your NSLog that currently logs objects for properties and crashes on primitive types (%@)?

Comment: see the answer above by matt

Answer (score -2):

The quick and dirty would be to override `debugDescription`:

```
-(NSString*)debugDescription {
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"My BOOL 1: %d, My Float: %f", self.myBool, self.myFoat];
    return str;
}
```

Of course, if your object is complex, this could be time consuming.

Comment: only if you like typing ;) or if it is only for one object!

Comment: @Daij-Djan Hence the disclaimer.