# How to get all static properties in Swift?

Tags: swift, properties, static

```
class AllDevice: Reflectable{

    static let LIGHT_ONOFF_NH_3A_R11_01_L12 = "LIGHT_ONOFF_NH_3A_R11_01_L12"

    static let PLUG_ONOFF_NH_3A_R11_01_B2AC = "PLUG_ONOFF_NH_3A_R11_01_B2AC"
    static let PLUG_POWER_NH_3A_R11_01_B2AC="PLUG_POWER_NH_3A_R11_01_B2AC"
    static let PLUG_ENERGY_NH_3A_R11_01_B2AC="PLUG_ENERGY_NH_3A_R11_01_B2AC"

    static let PLUG_ONOFF_NH_3A_R11_02_B2B8="PLUG_ONOFF_NH_3A_R11_02_B2B8"
    static let PLUG_POWER_NH_3A_R11_02_B2B8="PLUG_POWER_NH_3A_R11_02_B2B8"
    static let PLUG_ENERGY_NH_3A_R11_02_B2B8="PLUG_ENERGY_NH_3A_R11_02_B2B8"

    static let  PLUG_ONOFF_NH_3A_R11_03_B2D2="PLUG_ONOFF_NH_3A_R11_03_B2D2"
    static let PLUG_POWER_NH_3A_R11_03_B2D2="PLUG_POWER_NH_3A_R11_03_B2D2"
    static let PLUG_ENERGY_NH_3A_R11_03_B2D2="PLUG_ENERGY_NH_3A_R11_03_B2D2"
```

}

How to get all static properties in Swift?

I have tried below article ,but doesn't work
[How to list all Variables of a class in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928279/how-to-list-all-variables-of-a-class-in-swift)

Comment: your question is unclear, what are you trying to achieve? You want to output every variable is that right? Edit your answer and show how a sample output should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to implement `CustomReflectable`:

```
class AllDevice: CustomReflectable {

    static let LIGHT_ONOFF_NH_3A_R11_01_L12 = "LIGHT_ONOFF_NH_3A_R11_01_L12"

    static let PLUG_ONOFF_NH_3A_R11_01_B2AC = "PLUG_ONOFF_NH_3A_R11_01_B2AC"
    static let PLUG_POWER_NH_3A_R11_01_B2AC="PLUG_POWER_NH_3A_R11_01_B2AC"
    static let PLUG_ENERGY_NH_3A_R11_01_B2AC="PLUG_ENERGY_NH_3A_R11_01_B2AC"

    static let PLUG_ONOFF_NH_3A_R11_02_B2B8="PLUG_ONOFF_NH_3A_R11_02_B2B8"
    static let PLUG_POWER_NH_3A_R11_02_B2B8="PLUG_POWER_NH_3A_R11_02_B2B8"
    static let PLUG_ENERGY_NH_3A_R11_02_B2B8="PLUG_ENERGY_NH_3A_R11_02_B2B8"

    static let PLUG_ONOFF_NH_3A_R11_03_B2D2="PLUG_ONOFF_NH_3A_R11_03_B2D2"
    static let PLUG_POWER_NH_3A_R11_03_B2D2="PLUG_POWER_NH_3A_R11_03_B2D2"
    static let PLUG_ENERGY_NH_3A_R11_03_B2D2="PLUG_ENERGY_NH_3A_R11_03_B2D2"

    func customMirror() -> Mirror {
        return Mirror(self, children: [
            "LIGHT_ONOFF_NH_3A_R11_01_L12": self.dynamicType.LIGHT_ONOFF_NH_3A_R11_01_L12,
            "PLUG_ONOFF_NH_3A_R11_01_B2AC": self.dynamicType.PLUG_ONOFF_NH_3A_R11_01_B2AC,
            "PLUG_POWER_NH_3A_R11_01_B2AC": self.dynamicType.PLUG_POWER_NH_3A_R11_01_B2AC
            // etc...
        ])
    }
}

let device = AllDevice()
let m = Mirror(reflecting: device)
// you can access m.children now
```

As you can see, it's not fun and involve a lot of string literal. If you change value assigned to each device type, you have to update the mirror accordingly.

---

It is to implement your device type constants as an `enum`:

```
enum Device: String {
    case LIGHT_ONOFF_NH_3A_R11_01_L12 = "LIGHT_ONOFF_NH_3A_R11_01_L12"
    case PLUG_ONOFF_NH_3A_R11_01_B2AC = "PLUG_ONOFF_NH_3A_R11_01_B2AC"
    case PLUG_POWER_NH_3A_R11_01_B2AC = "PLUG_POWER_NH_3A_R11_01_B2AC"
    // etc..

    static let allDevices: [Device] = [
        .LIGHT_ONOFF_NH_3A_R11_01_L12,
        .PLUG_ONOFF_NH_3A_R11_01_B2AC,
        .PLUG_POWER_NH_3A_R11_01_B2AC
        // etc...
    ]
}
```

This way the complier can offer you some error checking.