# Is it possible to use a specific keys in a dictionary for a non static tableView with a custom tableViewCell

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, dictionary, custom-cell

I have an instance of a class, which i want to use like a dictionary as datasource for a tableView.
here is the instance AlimentTest:

```
class AlimentModificationData {
    
    static var AlimentTest : AlimentObject = AlimentObject(nomAliment: "Amandes", poids: 100, calories: 108, proteines: 21, lipides: 53, glucides: 8, aRetinol: 8, aBetacarotene: 1, vitamineC: 0.8, vitamineB1: 0.18, calcium: 248, omega3: 0.06, comments: "fffffff sdsddsdsd", premierBooleen: false, optimize: false)
    
    static var listNutriments : [String] = ["aRetinol", "aBetacarotene", "vitamineC", "vitamineB1", "calcium", "omega3"]
}
```

I want to use this instance "AlimentTest" for a tableView, with a customcell with an identifier.
But i want to use **only the keys which are specified in the static array named listNutriments**.

At the end, i want my tableView to display something like this for dequeureusableCell:

aRetinol             8
aBetacarotene        1
vitamineC            0.8
vitamineB1           0.18
calcium              248
omega3               0.06

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create AlimentTest method, that generates the dictionary and then use listNutriments to filter it
e.g.

```
extension AlimentObject {
    func asDict [String : Any] {
        var dict: [String : Any] = [:]
        dict["nomAliment"] = nomAliment
        dict["poids"] = poids
        dict["calories"] = calories
        dict["proteines"] = proteines
        dict["lipides"] = lipides

        ...here fill more info to dict

        return dict
    }
}
```

Then use it to generate list based on your filter name:

```
let filtered =  alimentObject.asDict.filter({ listNutriments.contains($0.key)})
```

or if you want to make it without manually creating asDict method, use this (based on [How to list all Variables of a class in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928279/how-to-list-all-variables-of-a-class-in-swift)):

```
extension AlimentObject {
    func listPropertiesWithValues(reflect: Mirror? = nil) -> [String : Any] {
        var dict = [String : Any]()
        let mirror = reflect ?? Mirror(reflecting: self)
        if mirror.superclassMirror != nil {
            self.listPropertiesWithValues(reflect: mirror.superclassMirror)
        }

        for (index, attr) in mirror.children.enumerated() {
            if let property_name = attr.label {
                dict[property_name] = attr.value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then you would use:

```
let filtered =  alimentObject.listPropertiesWithValues().filter({ listNutriments.contains($0.key)})
```

Comment: but i need a Float dictionary!
I know, i am a beginner ..

Comment: Could you tell me please vytick how to do it?