# Perform same action for many objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

If I have 100 UITextFields,

`myTextfFeld1`, `myTextField2`...and so on until `mytextField100`

...and they all perform the same action, say change `myTextField1.alpha = 0.4` to `myTextField1.alpha = 1`.

Rather than write this out 100 times is there a more efficient way of doing this

I had a look here [iOS looping over an object's properties and adding actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542997/ios-looping-over-an-objects-properties-and-adding-actions) but it still means adding all the `UITextFields` into the array.

Comment: Why don't you create them in an array to start with?

Comment: Having 100 ivars is silly. Use an NSArray or IBOutletCollection.

Comment: I haven't got 100 ivars, just an exaggeration during my explanation of what I was tying to put across in my question.  Agreed with both comments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Please, no!***

[Like this.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umDr0mPuyQc)

Use an array, seriously. **Don't you dare having 100 instance variables named `textField1` to `textField100`!**

---

Just in order to *actually answer* your question: you still *can* do this. Again, I strongly discourage doing it, but just for completeness' sake, here's the code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    NSString *ivarName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myTextField%d", i];
    UITextField *tf = [self valueForKey:ivarName];
    [tf doWhateverYouWant];
}
```

Reflection in Objective-C is awesome, isn't it? Not quite when abused.

Comment: I would dream of it its just example text for SO

Comment: @JSA986 Sorry, I don't understand what you mean, please elaborate.

Comment: I wouldn't actually have a 100 instance variables named `myText1`etc.  They were hypothetical instance variable for simplicity when posting my question.  They have much better naming conventions than that ;-)  Thanks for answer thats exactly was after!

Answer (score 1):

You can define an outlet collection and connect all of the textfields to it from the XIB:

```
 @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutletCollection(UITextField) NSArray *textFields;
```

Then you can loop over the `textFields` array.

Comment: ...or instead of looping, you can use the method `–makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:` on the `NSArray`.

Comment: @holex, true, assuming that the method takes an object parameter (so couldn't be used for setting the `alpha` for example)

Comment: yep, you are absolutely right, it needs a little play with the `NSInvocation` for the non-object parameters. it depends on the code-pattern the poster has chosen, but that was not part of the original question, I think.

Answer (score -2):

Use a loop and an array for the textfields.
e.g.

```
int i = 0
do textfield[i].alpha = 1
i = i+1
until i = 100
```

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C. Answers should be in the same language.

Comment: Are you allowed? Sure. But to be helpful, your answer should provide usable code appropriate to the question.