# Building a flexible editing form for attributes of an NSManagedObject subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, key-value-observing

I have an NSManagedObject subclass with 30 different attributes. In the app, the user should be able to edit (most of) the attributes in a table. There are 3 attributes that get automatically set based on the values of other combinations of attributes.

Example:

```
@implementation myNSManagedObjectSubclass
@dynamic one; // edited by user in form
@dynamic two; // edited by user in form
@dynamic three; // edited by user in form
@dynamic four; // edited by user in form
@dynamic five; // edited by user in form
@dynamic icon; // automatically set based values of above 5 items
@end
```

I have two questions:

1) *Regarding building a form in a table view that the user can use to edit the objects*: Other than hard-coding the content of the table view, how can I get my table view to build cells only for the attributes it needs to show? My current idea is to use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269372/loop-through-all-object-properties-at-runtime) to iterate through all the properties of my object and have a binary "display mask" that the table view can use to determine whether or not it should display a cell for a particular item. Is there a better way?

2) *Regarding automatically setting one attribute based the value of the others*: How? I think KVO comes into play here (I need the icon attribute to update on the screen as soon as one of the attributes it depends on changes) but I'm new to Core Data and not sure from what I read whether I can add KVO to NSManagedObject subclasses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad two - I concur with Wain that KVO can be useful. However, another standard way is to override the setters in your custom managed object classes.

Ad one - iterating through attributes like look like a nice abstraction, but I doubt it will save you any work. As you point out, you still have to create a "binary display mask" to determine which attribute to make editable. Seems pretty messy once an attribute is added somewhere...

I have had a good experience in this kind of situation (40 entities, 100s of attributes) with a simple "mapping" plist that can be used for this purpose. Entering the attributes into a plist (in the desired order) and adding other properties is really very fast and simple - and a flexible solution should something change.

You can still iterate through the attributes via NSEntityDescription to generate your initial plist.

Comment: Oh man... How could I not think of overriding setters? That's so straightforward. Thank you.

Can you please elaborate on the plist solution?

Comment: Plist: dictionary of entity names, arrays of attributes with one or more additional piece of information. We used this to translate e.g. JSON objects into existing data structures. You could set the order and "editable" of any attribute quite easily in this way.

Answer (score 1):

For 2, yes, KVO can help you with this. The attribute would also usually be transient and updated when the object awakes from fetch as well as when the observed properties change.

For 1, consider using the `NSEntityDescription`, specifically `attributesByName` so you can automatically get the table display content (if you want to display the inner name) and the attribute information (so you don't display the transient (derived) attributes).